# Enable/Disable Wifi on Android in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, wifi

I am trying to enable or disable Wifi from Unity on my Android device.
I tried to do the different things I found on the forum without success.

If I do:

```
using(var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
{
     string wifiServiceName = unityPlayer.Get<string>("WIFI_SERVICE");
     using(var wifiManager = unityPlayer.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", wifiServiceName))
     {
         wifiManager.Call("setWifiEnabled", false);
     }
}
```

I have an error saying that `WIFI_SERVICE` doesn't exist.

If I do:

```
using (AndroidJavaObject activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
{
    using (var wifiManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService","wifi"))
    {
        wifiManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setWifiEnabled", false);
    }   
}
```

I have an error saying that `setWifiEnabled` is not a function, (nor a static function if I do `CallStatic`).

I have my `manifest.xml` correctly merged, I can check that I have all the permissions on the application manager.

I spent few hours trying to figure out how to do that and I am stuck!

Does anyone know a simple way to do so?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Benjamin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled(boolean)), `setWifiEnabled` takes `bool` as parameter and  *returns `bool`* too.

Your second code is almost close.
You got the parameter right but failed to provide the return type. You put `AndroidJavaObject` as the return type instead of `bool`.

In your second code, simply replace `wifiManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setWifiEnabled", false);` with `wifiManager.Call<bool>("setWifiEnabled", false);`.

This should work, assuming that you have your permission in place. One advice to you is to put your code in a try catch clause. This will prevent some weird behavior if something is null or failed in your Android function calls.

```
public bool setWifiEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    using (AndroidJavaObject activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var wifiManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "wifi"))
            {
                return wifiManager.Call<bool>("setWifiEnabled", enabled);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public bool isWifiEnabled()
{
    using (AndroidJavaObject activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var wifiManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "wifi"))
            {
                return wifiManager.Call<bool>("isWifiEnabled");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Permissions   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />` and 
  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />`

Comment: com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer, should we change to be the package name in Unity?