# How to get BSSID of wifi i'm connecting to in Unity (C#)?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, wifi, bssid

How can I get BSSID (MAC address of the wifi router I'm connecting in, not my device MAC Address) in my Unity Game App on Android and iOS phone?

I have tried these method but none of them working.I check the result by printing it on game scene. Please help

***Method 1:** This code work fine and get the correct BSSID info but it's only work on Editor, when I build it to Android App it's not working, return string is nothing (Not null but empty value).

```
 string mac = "";
 var card = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault();
 if (card == null)
     return null;
 else
 {
     byte[] bytes = card.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes();
     for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
     {
         mac = string.Concat(mac + (string.Format("{0}", bytes[i].ToString("X2"))));
         if (i != bytes.Length - 1)
         {
             //This is just for formating the final result
             mac = string.Concat(mac + ":");
         }
     }
     mac = card.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
     return mac;
 }
```

***Method 2:** I'm using AndroidJavaClass to call an android function to get BSSID on Android Phone as in Unity document. More info about [AndroidJavaClass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.Call.html) in Unity and [WifiInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getBSSID()) class of Android

```
 string mac = "";
 AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.wifi.WifiInfo");
 mac = jc.Call<string>("getBSSID");
```

I also add android permission for reading wifi state by modifing "AndroidManifest.xml" file at location "[Project Location]\Assets\Plugins\Android" with the code below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Since this method not working on Editor, I build and run this on Android Phone but no string is return. Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to make plugins in order to do this on mobile devices.

For iOS, you have to convert this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5198716/3785314) into a plugin then call it from C#. There are many Unity iOS plugin tutorials out there that can get you started on this.

For Android, you should first [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39115861/3785314) if Wifi is enabled before getting the BSSID with the code below:

```
public static string getSSID()
{
    string tempSSID = "";

    try
    {
        using (var activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
        {
            using (var wifiManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "wifi"))
            {
                tempSSID = wifiManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getConnectionInfo").Call<string>("getSSID");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return tempSSID;
}

public static string getBSSID()
{
    string tempBSSID = "";

    try
    {
        using (var activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
        {
            using (var wifiManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "wifi"))
            {
                tempBSSID = wifiManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getConnectionInfo").Call<string>("getBSSID");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return tempBSSID;
}
```

Don't forget to include the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```cs
    string bytes2Mac(byte[] bytes) {
        string[] m = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
        string ret = "";
        foreach (byte b in bytes)
        {
            int low = b & 0x0F;
            int hi = (b & 0xF0) >> 4;
            ret += m[hi] + m[low];
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public string ReturnMacAddress()
    {
        string macAddr = "";
        var network = new AndroidJavaClass("java.net.NetworkInterface").CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getNetworkInterfaces");
        while(network.Call<Boolean>("hasMoreElements")) {
            var d = network.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("nextElement");
            var address = d.Call<byte[]>("getHardwareAddress");
            var ifname = d.Call<string>("getName");
            if (address != null && ifname == "wlan0") {
                macAddr = bytes2Mac(address);
                break;
            }
        }
        return macAddr;
    }
```