# Turn off Internet connection on the Unity3D mobile games

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple issue but there is no straightforward answer to this issue.

How to disable entire internet connection when Unity3D games started?  For Instance, create a total offline mobile game?

+I have Unity3D Pro version.
+Unity HW  statistics disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see tihs post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111324/enable-disable-wifi-on-android-in-unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do but not simple. I assume when you say mobile devices, this includes both Android and iOS.

This functionality is not build into Unity. There are two steps to do this:

**What to do:**

**1**.Disable Wifi

**2**.Disable Mobile Data

The entire internet connection should be killed when you do both of this.

**How to do it:**

You will have to make a plugin to do this. This is platform dependent and you must know basic Java (for Android) and Object-C(for iOS) in order to do this.

Google *"How to disable wifi on Android with Java"* and also *"How to disable mobile data on Android with Java"*. Convert that into a plugin. That's basically a  simple function that you can call from C# to toggle wifi or mobile data on/off.

Do the-same thing for iOS. Take the Object-C code and turn into a plugin then call it from C#.

As for how to build the plugin for each platform, this can be found with a little bit of research. There is no other way to do this. My [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111324/enable-disable-wifi-on-android-in-unity/39115861#39115861) post shows how to enable/disable wifi on Android only but that's just part of what to do in this answer. You still need a way to disable mobile data.

Comment: On top of this...*why?* Why would you want to prevent *all other apps* from accessing the internet while your game is running?

Comment: If the comment is directed to me then I don't really know why. Maybe OP had a good reason and would like to hear it too

Comment: No, not at you Programmer, just a followup to be read *after* your answer.

Comment: Oh ok. I will wait to see if OP will reply. I want to know too